# Cordova ImagePicker Firebase Upload Error

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, blob, firebase-storage

I have a Cordova image picker that lets the user to select one image and then I am trying to upload that to Firebase. I have something like this.

```
        window.imagePicker.getPictures(function (results) {

                var file = results[0];

                var metadata = {
                    contentType: 'image/jpeg'
                };

                var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                var id = user.uid;
            try {
                var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                    var blob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: "image/jpeg" });

                    var uploadTask = storageRef.child('profileimages/' + '/' + id + '/' + file.name).put(Blob, metadata);

                }
                reader.onerror = function (e) {
                    console.log("Failed file read: " + e.toString());
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
...
}
```

I am getting `Failed to execute readAsArrayBuffer on FileReader parameter 1 is not of type Blob`. I copy pasted the code to convert the filepath into image, but it doesn't work.